# LowBatteryReceiver does not exist and FATAL EXCEPTION: main errors android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fatal-error, runtimeexception, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to make an application that when a toggle button is on starts a broadcast that check if battery low and disable wifi. Instead when the toggle is off starts another broadcast and the wifi starts. The problem is that the application crashes when i press the button. this is the code for the toggle and wifi:

```
   public void getToggle(View view) { 
    // Is the toggle on?
   boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked(); 
    if (on) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName compName = 
    new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
        LowBatteryReceiver.class);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        compName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    } else {                
           PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
           ComponentName compName = 
           new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
           LowBatteryReceiver.class);
           pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
           compName,
           PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
           PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);           
      }
    }


//wifi enable/disable
   public class LowBatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
}


public class OkBatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

This is the manifest. The receiver are inside `<application>` and `<activity>` tags:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/battery"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
     android:name=".LowBatteryReceiver"
     android:enabled="false" >
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
     android:name=".OkBatteryReceiver"
     android:enabled="false" >
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".about"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">    
        </activity>
</application>
```

How can i resolve? I can't find the error..
edit with logcat:
[image: Logcat]

Comment: `<receiver>` tags in the `<application>` node is fine, but they are not allowed in the `<activity>` node, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Also, can you post the whole output of the error from your LogCat?

Comment: So i have to write the `receiver` outside the activity right? Ok just a minute and i update my quest with the logcat.

Comment: That's correct. You can read about it in the developer documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Comment: same error :( i've edited my quest.

Comment: Are the `LowBatteryReceiver` and `OkBatteryReceiver` inner classes of your `MainActivity`?

Comment: yes, they are.. The code i post above is a part inside the MainActivity. Have i to declare something else?

Comment: I've edit again with whole manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference from your manifest to the Receiver classes are not right. Right now, you reference them like they are a normal class within your package. Since they are inner classes, you should reference them like this (see the `android:name` attribute):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MainActivity$OkBatteryReceiver"
    android:enabled="false" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Inner classes are referenced by the `$`.

Comment: Fantastic! It works thanks!! Only another one question.. Is it possible set a battery level like "30%" as BATTERY_LOW? i mean, i think that with actual code the wifi turns off only when BATTERY_LOW is true.. I want  that wifi turns off for example when the battery level is 30%. Is it pssible from my code?

Comment: Great it works! You should ask that as a separate question on this site.